# Create an unordered_map with custom object as key

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I want to create an `std::unordered_map` with `Node` as the key. I have already overloaded the operator `==` and `<`. I have also defined a hash function. However, it is giving me error:

`C2280: std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &): attempting to reference a deleted function`

Here is my code for the `Node` class:

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node() {
  word = Word();
}

Node::Node(Word input_word) : word(input_word) {}

Node::Node(const Node& other) {
  word = other.word;
  connection = other.connection;
}

Node::~Node() {
}

bool Node::operator<(const Node& other) {
  return (word < other.get_word());
}

bool Node::operator==(const Node& other) {
  if (word == other.word) {
    if (connection.size() == other.connection.size()) {
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < connection.size(); i++) {
        if (connection[i] != other.connection[i]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

Word Node::get_word() const {
  return word;
}

int Node::add_connection(Edge* input_node) {
  connection.push_back(input_node);
  return SUCCESS;
}

vector<Edge*> Node::retrieve_connection() const{
  return connection;
}


namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<Node> {
    size_t operator()(const Node& other) const {
      return hash<string>()(other.get_word().get_string()) ^
             hash<int>()(other.retrieve_connection().size());
    }
  };
}
```

I am very confused about what I should add next. I have tried most suggestions that I can find on websites, but none of them works.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the complete error messages from the compiler.

Comment: "*I have tried most suggestions that I can find on websites, but none of them works.*" It's hard for us to help you when we can't try suggestions, get error messages with our preferred compiler, simplify the code to see if the error goes away, and so on.

Comment: I had to make a lot of assumptions about your `Node` and `Word` classes (many of them bad coding style; e.g. you should use `= default` for constructors and destructors when possible, or in this case just use the Rule of Zero and don't explicitly define them at all), but when I did everything compiled perfectly. Please share the full error message and see if you can provide a complete (non-)working *minimal* example.